# How to reset Visual Studio debugging options to default?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 Community, if I click Debug->Options I get these controllable options:

[image]

Also, after I click Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings I get these:

[image]

I am currently experiencing bizarre step-over behavior and other odd behaviors during debugging - for example some exceptions are being caught and others are not.

Instead of isolating the particular option and twiddling with it, I'd rather just reset all of the above options to default settings. However, I do not see how to achieve this. Can you someone please explain how to reset them back to defaults?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Go to Tools->Import and Export Settings and you can reset to default settings for whatever environment you're in.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx

To restore the default exception settings, press the Restore button on the Exception Settings window. It looks like a checklist thing for some reason.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx

Comment: Or just right-click inside the Exception Settings window and click: Restore Defaults (VS2017)

Comment: @LeroyMeijer has the easiest solution. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Launch Visual Studio 2017 (may be same with 2015)
Menu

-> Tools

-> Import and Export Settings...

-> Select 'Reset all settings' radio button

-> Next

-> Select 'No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings' radio button if you want to reset VS to a fresh install settings

-> Choose 'General' or setting you want to restore to.

-> Finish

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the top right icon that's on the Exception Settings section:

[image: Restore default settings button in exception settings panel]

If you hover the mouse over this button you will see it says 'Restore the list to the default settings' which is exactly what you are looking for.

Note that if you restore default in the Tools menu instead, you will overwrite other changes as well, not only Exception settings.