# Unable to Hot Reload on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, hot-reload, visual-studio-2022

I moved my web app from Visual Studio 2019 to 2022 (Preview 7) but I am unable to hot-reload even small changes like changing `if(a=b)` to `if(a!=b)` and will require stopping the debugger, and I am unsure what is the 'COMPLUS_ForceENC' environment variable, couldn't find anything about it.

When I create a new web app, hot reload works very well on C# and cshtml.

this is the error shown when I change anything to my original app:

> Error ENC2004: Changes made in project require restarting the application: Changes are not allowed when the debugger has been attached to an already running process. Consider setting 'COMPLUS_ForceENC' environment variable before launching your process.

Comment: But what is your question? What do you expect of us? 

VS2022 is not released yet. I.e. bugs are expected. Did you report this to Microsoft?

Comment: Yes I did, but I don't know how long it'll take, I just want to know how to set the COMPLUS_ForceENC environment variable, nothing came on google regarding this variable!

Comment: There are a number of hits when you google "COMPLUS_ForceENC". But it might not be the solution to your problem.

Comment: I just installed the 2022 RTM and I am getting that issue on a .NET Core 3.1 Web API Project when I do a very simple code change.

Comment: Hot reload is not working on Cshtml files in .NET Core 3.1 MVC application either.

Comment: Official version is out now but I'm experiencing the same issue. Anyone reported this yet? Any page we could follow for this?

Comment: From the outside, I'm trying to help Microsoft get this fixed. Do you have anything **helpful** to add? Maybe even a polite "I've experienced this too" with any details you can muster. Examples of how MS might reproduce failures when running from Visual Studio would be helpful, I think.

**https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45519** 

Perhaps that is the main issue to track this, since it has some responses? Also relevant:

* https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45190
* https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44568
* https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39715

Answer (score 44):

I was blaming VS for un-functional Hot Reload, but in my case it was caused by trying to Debug ( F5 ) and hot reloading at the same time. Hot reload icon [image] did not work at all for blazor apps.

The solution was quite simple. The app needs to be started  **without** debugging ( Ctrl+F5 ) [image]

After that hot reload works fine.

Comment: Indeed.  I'm actually building a Blazor Wasm hosted in ASP.NET Core and HOT RELOAD doesn't work at all even with CTRL-F5.  Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.0.5

Comment: I was doing this with a web project. Almost gave up on it as I have been doing a control f5 debug for 20 years.. this solved the issue of the Hot Reload not working in visual studio  because I was running though IIS / IIS Express

Comment: How does MS think this even tenable? Pretty much the only reason I ever want to hot reload is after fixing an issue I discovered WHILE DEBUGGING? What use is this if you can't debug and hot reload?

Comment: This is not an answer. Hot reload is only useful PRECISELY WHILE DEBUGGING.  What goes on in the heads of the 43 people who up-voted this non-answer is completely beyond me.

Comment: @Mike Nakis: I was expecting to use the feature in Debug mode as well. Have you figured out how to do it ? At the time of the answer I could not make it work in Debug. I am happy to update the answer.

Comment: There is a great number of reasons why hot reload may stop working, so there is no single trick that will work for everyone.  (Except, perhaps, disabling hot reload, or disabling debugging, which though are not solutions.) It is possible to collect a long list of possible reasons by searching for "hot reload" or "edit-and-continue" on stackoverflow, but that's a project in and of itself. There even exist some answers to other questions that attempt to compile a list of possible remedies. Of course trying them involves a lot of trial-and-error.

Comment: Hot Reload *is* supposed to work in debug mode and has worked for blazor applications. With that said, it's capricious

Comment: @G.Stoynev I'll say. If you update a `[Parameter]` that then updates a CSS variable through the `style` attribute, the entire component gets deleted from the DOM and you need to fully restart the application to get it working again. Hot Reload in Blazor is a joke.

Answer (score 30):

Late to the party, but today this started driving me nuts as stepping in the debugger threw this issue every single time I went to the next statement.

Solution for me was

1. Press the Hot Reload icon in the toolbar, then Settings from the icon's context menu (or access via Tools > Settings > Debugging)
2. Disable "Enable Hot Reload and Edit and Continue when debugging"

[image]

Sadly I've been unable to get Hot Reload working while debugging, but its not really an issue for me.

Comment: I had this same issue. I was getting the error message just by stepping through the debugger! Turning this off resolved the problem.

Comment: @BrandonTull I had same issue, just by pressing F10 to do a step in the debug, caused the message to appear, which is crazy, a clear bug. Once I restarted visual studio the issue dissapeared.

Comment: Hot reload was working fine in Debug until just now, and I have no idea what changed. Being able to use it only without debugging is pretty useless.

Comment: VS 17.4.5 right now and these options are checked and disabled.  Hot reload is still not working at all while debugging

Comment: @marc-roussel  I saw the options disabled too (VS 17.5.0), but then realized I had the Debugger turned on. Once I stopped the Debugger I was able to modify (e.g. disable) those checkboxes.

Comment: best solution is to turn that rubbish off. It bugs at random, rebuilding doesn't help, only restarting windows. Almost 1 year later and Microsoft still hasn't fixed

Comment: Still useful in 2024... :-/

Answer (score 10):

First of all, hot reload should work for both `Ctrl + F5` *and* `F5` debugging, so the accepted answer is wrong.

In my case hot reload was not working because my debug configuration was named differently than "Debug", it was named "LocalDebug" (but I did set all the settings correctly).

There's an issue at MS's github here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43910

Comment: This still solves the issue in Visual Studio 2022 17.8 in 2023 - Absurd

Comment: +1 So after reading this, I changed appsettings.Development.json to appsettings.Debug.json which matched the name (Debug) in my Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 7):

Might be a coincidence, but after updating from 17.0.1 to 17.0.2 it started working. It's strange because in the update log there's no mention to such a bug fix. Try updating to the latest version.

UPDATE
Seems that I only got this working on my new .NET 6 project. In the old one migrated to .NET 6 this still happens. Maybe in projects that are not fully migrated to .NET 6 and still using the old startup.cs file won't work correctly. In debug mode, the update notification shows up, but content does not change until a browser refresh.If not in debug mode, refreshing the browser does nothing.

UPDATE 2
Found out that in a new .net 6 Asp.net Web page project, the Hot reload works well if I change .razor files, but in .cshtml files I need to refresh the browser to see changes. I have both file types because I'm using razor pages + Blazor in the same project.

If you try to create a .Net 6 Blazor project I'm almost sure Hot Reload will work.

UPDATE 3
I have now opened an Issue in Dotnet Github. You can follow the issue there. [github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38809](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38809)

Comment: Thanks, that's actually my problem exactly! i am not sure what is missing or how to "fully migrate" to .Net6 !

Comment: tryed to update and hot reload while debugging, still doesn't work for me even with an out-of-the-box project using the .net6 template.

Comment: Mine resolved after updating from 17.0.0 to 17.0.2. It's sort of bugs that destroy Rockets!

Comment: I have now opened an Issue in Dotnet Github. You can follow the issue there.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38809

Comment: Blazor WASM hot reload does NOT work - tested extensively on VS Code and  VS2022 with .net 6.0.100.

Comment: @Greg did not test that out, but you should post that in the issue I opened in github. They should know about it.

Comment: Given up posting issues in github - they release stuff and then "pretend" its working and the train moves on.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/blazor-hot-reload-not-working/1480369   Sayed Hashimi from microsoft says it does NOT work on release 17.0.3 - Im am in agreement.

Comment: Oh, they fix tons of bugs on every release, but in the release notes they never mention more than a few, because that would make them look bad, and they never mention the particularly embarrassing ones that remained stagnant for years before eventually getting fixed because that would also make them look bad.  So, pay no attention to the release notes, they are nothing but public relations propaganda.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I made a stupid mistake of trying to Hot Reload an application run in **Release** configuration. Make sure it is **Debug** :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

VisualStudio 2022 GA version doesn't works for me either :( looks i'm not the only one, i've noticed i've a icon for the hot reload function different from the one shown in the Microsoft promotional videos, mine is a flame, while the working version seems to have two flames that forms a circle :(

i've found [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/update-on-net-hot-reload-progress-and-visual-studio-2022-highlights/)

> *In Visual Studio 2022 GA release Hot Reload support for Blazor WebAssembly when using the Visual Studio debugger isn’t enabled yet.
> You can still get Hot Reload If you start your app through Visual
> Studio without the debugger, and we are working to resolve this in the
> next Visual Studio update.

if i start the program without debugger attached I have Hot Reload, or i can run the app with the debugger without the hot reload, which is expected by the article linked above but the [Launch Event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhqsLNT1fGA&t=2729s) is quite misleading as they never mention this nor shown which button is pressed during the demos to start blazor webasm with hot reload working... Anyway they doesn't show debugger and hot reload working together for blazor webasm, so it looks like it's all in our minds :( ... we need to wait

Comment: Its extremely misleading - showing videos of Blazor server side hot reload working but NOT saying that this does not work on wasm. I have wasted so much time on this and submitted 5 different bug explanations throughout the preview versions and the release version. No more - just a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

While trying to resolve a separate problem, I enabled native debugging in my project, which caused this problem. After disabling it again, I'm able to hot reload.

https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-native-code-debugging

> 1. With your project open, select the "Project" tab, then choose "appname Properties…".
> 2. Select "Debug" on the left pane.
> 3. Check the "Enable native code debugging" box to enable it. **Uncheck it to disable it.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Worked for me in a VS2022 Windows Forms .Net Framework 4.8 application.

Answer (score 3):

I know this might be one of the very first things most people will try, but I just restarted Visual Studio and it worked again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was due to I have disabled Razor Source Generator `<UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>` in the `.csproj` file. Setting it back to `true` fixed the issue.

Comment: This has worked multiple times for me across multiple projects, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Might help someone. I removed reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation in my Web project and code in my startup and HotReload working now...

Comment: "code in my startup", what code? please elaborate...

Comment: @OJB1 what seemed to work for me was to REm this out //services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

I also removed the reference from the Web project in VS (didn't need it anymore)

Answer (score 1):

In my case , it was due to I have not used `hotReloadProfile` in my `launchSettings.json` file:

```
"IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "hotReloadProfile": "aspnetcore", 
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to save your project, close it. Shut dowm visual studio and start it again. Often errors disappear instantly..

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem started after having enabled the native code debugging.
I set debugger process (back) to 'Managed only', and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this error seemingly out nowhere but was able to resolve it eventually.
I'm not sure of both steps are necessary but what i did was:

1. I reset the VS Debugging options, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988389/how-to-reset-visual-studio-debugging-options-to-default): `Tools -> Import and Export Settings`
2. I restarted VS

Comment: it works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Hot Reload issue and the following steps helped me fix it.

1. Close Visual Studio and delete all the `bin` and `obj` folders in your solution.
2. Remove `.vs` (hidden) folder in the solution root.

And this is my (default) Hot Reload settings:
[image: Hot Reload settings]

Hope this might help someone.

*My original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77699053/826611*

Answer (score 0):

For me there was another VBCSCompiler process that was running. Hot Reload worked after I ended that extra process in the Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with hot reload not working, the cause was this line:

```cs
app.UseResponseCompression();
```

See more info her:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43939#issuecomment-1245382809

Answer (score 0):

Another reason I'm finding for Hot Reload not working is that there's UI changes already occurring when the Hot Reload is triggered.

I have found that if I execute my hot reload on a page too quickly, it will throw the hot reload error. However if I turn inspect on and wait for all page / network updates to stop before I hit hot reload, the hot reload will succeed.

This works in Blazor WASM both in and out of the Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Hot Reload was not working.

I was using VS 2022 and .Net Core 6 and using the service like this

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

When I remove

```
AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
```

Hot Reload work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

My fix was to only have ONE startup project.
Removed my API as a startup project and ran my .Net MAUI app as a single project.

Hope this can help someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post this just in case, but my issue with it was that when saving it was not hot reloading. Setting it from the hot reload dropdown fixed it for me.

(Edit as I am unable to post images: Hot Reload drop down --> Hot Reload on File Save)