# Hot Reload not working in Visual Studio 2022 .Net 6 Razor projects

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, hot-reload

We just upgraded all but one of our web app projects from .NET Core 3.1 projects to .NET 6 in our solution. These were ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects using Razor. Here are the results we're seeing with respect to Hot Reload:

1. The .NET 6 projects hot reload doesn't seem to work. Hot Reload is enabled, but our Front End is never updated. Refreshing the page doesn't seem to show the updates either.
2. The ASP.NET Core 3.1 project hot reload is working as expected.

When we run these projects in VS 2019, we can refresh the pages in any of our projects and we will see the updates. Are there some settings that we're missing here?

Comment: What exactly is not reloading? If it is razor views - try answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65438390/2501279).

Comment: You're a life saver! This is our solution. We hadn't updated RazorRuntimeCompilation and we needed to and one setting in launchsettings.json. This has been the reason why we've been hesitant to move onto VS 2022. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Big Thank you to Guru Stron! His comment in my question directed me to where I should've looked. We had to:

1. Update our **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** Nuget package
2. Add this to our launchsettings.json: **ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES** to "**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation**"

This answer solved our issue - [.NET Core MVC Page Not Refreshing After Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639969/net-core-mvc-page-not-refreshing-after-changes/65438390#65438390)

Comment: For me the NuGet package was enough

Comment: Hmm.... I'm having this trouble with an MVC app and trying to fix.  I don't even have that package. Anyone know hot to fix for MVC?

Answer (score 15):

**First, Make sure all options are selected**

[image]

**In Hot reload, You can select `Hot Reload On File Save`(Not selected by default), Then VS will hot reload after you `ctrl+s`;**

[image]

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, we've tried this and it still doesn't work for us.

Comment: I think checking the third hot reload option in Tools options worked for me in my MVC app.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after trying everything including rolling back the version and adding `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` to `Program.cs` still didn't work. What I did was literally re-check the "Hot reload on file save" option when you click on the down arrow to bring up the menu on the hot reload button from the menu bar. That did the trick for me.

Hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the other good suggestions, my case was different.

I had the same issue. **There were 2 projects running**, and the first one was the API. After starting the API project separately *(right-click on the Project name, Debug>Start..)* the only project I actually ran was my Blazor WASM. **Then the Hot Reload started to work** for the Blazor WASM project.

Hope it helps, if anyone has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following steps fixed it.

1. Close Visual Studio and delete all the `bin` and `obj` folders in your solution.
2. Remove `.vs` (hidden) folder in the solution root.

And this is my (default) Hot Reload settings:
[image: Hot Reload settings]

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I deselect '*Enable native code debugging*' then Hot reload working:
**Project** > **Properties** > **Debug** > **General** > **Open debug launch profiles UI** > **IIS Express**.

[image]