# Hot Reload not working Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, hot-reload

I am working on an ASP.NET core MVC project. I want to enable Hot Reload on my Razor Pages. I keep getting the following error once I make a change to a .cshtml file under Views/Controller and save it.

[image]

My Hot Reload Settings
[image]

I'm starting the app without debugging. How do I get Hot Reload to work ?

Comment: The error suggests (since it says its not expected) something abnormal with Hot Reload went wrong.  I would maybe try reinstalling Visual Studio.  Maybe also look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72296892/hot-reload-not-working-in-visual-studio-2022-net-6-razor-projects